# Are too many internal links (menus links, footer links, etc.) considered "duplicate content"?

Tags: asp.net, seo, duplicates, googlebot

I have a **horizontal top navigational bar** that contains links with menus and submenus to the pages on my site.  These are included in my master pages and resource files.

I also have a **vertical menu** with the same links to the same pages.

I also have some links (legal, contact, etc.) **in my footer**.

The reason I have my website set up like this is because many of my clients are older engineers who aren't too savvy with the internet, and this gives makes the website "easier to navigate" for those types of viewers.

Perhaps this photo will make things more clear:

[image: Snapshot of USS Website]

My question is, is that am I being potentially punished, SEO-wise, by SE bots for having "**duplicate content**", or "**duplicate links**"?  If so, is it recommended that I just take the vertical menu in the left column down and put other things there?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might be better served on programmers.se or webmasters.se

Comment: My suggestion for posting the question elsewhere was that your question felt a little more subjective to me because you were asking more about form/function of multiple links on the site as opposed to actually coding then up. Yes you were also asking about SEO, which I think webmasters and general programming could accomplish better. It's nothing personal, and I didn't downvote it myself, I was just trying to get you the best answer as quick as possible. As for the "programming cartoon" well that's a remnant from the "old days" of StackOverflow. 8^D

Comment: Okay, thanks Dillie-O ... it's just that stackoverflow has so many more members than webmasters SE, and I've learned so much through stackoverflow, that I prefer to post here above other sites like asp.net, etc. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not duplicate content.

Duplicate content is about larger amounts of text (non markup). Virtually every site has some duplicate, usually on every page, for stuff like headers and footers. That is not what Google or the Panda update is concerned with.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  This is the answer I was hoping for!  I'm still trying to get a handle on the Panda, Penguin, and Venice updates, but this solves one issue.  Thank you for taking the time to read my question and respond -- much appreciated!

Comment: My advice is to not get too hung up with the various algorithm updates. Rather just focus on useful and legitimate content. After all, when Google alters its algorithm, it's trying to better rank sites that provide exactly that.